# how to extract specific string from following using regex? the best way

Tags: c#, regex

I  have following kind of string

```
/asdfd-dfsdf-sadfdfsdf-safdsfok-785452145x/dshfkjsd-sdfsd-sdfsdfsn-sfsdfe-jsdfdss/9?sdf=sdfsdf32d-0sdf8d-49sfe-asdf7-4fsfs32dd73880
```

out of which i wan to extract only 785452145x

What would be the best way? i use C# 2.0

Comment: `string newString = "785452145x";`... If you need something better than that, we will need more details. What do you mean by "I want to extract"? Do you need to match a specific pattern that "785452145x" fits?

Comment: Aw c'mon.  At least try to answer the question, and your answer will probably do the best to demonstrate the absurdity of the question :) Guessing requirements is fun, I do that all day long it seems...

Comment: @mellamokb what do you mean? I already provided the most efficient answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// setup the input data
string inputString = "/asdfd...";

// pull out string from beginning to second slash
// firstPart = "/asdfd...fok-785452145x/"
string firstPart = inputString.Substring(0, inputString.IndexOf("/", 1));

// grab last data element after the last hyphen
// lastElement = "785452145x";
string lastElement = firstPart.Substring(firstPart.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);

// do something with lastElement...
```

Comment: Guys i was looking for an approach to capture the text that is just before 2nd / and after the last - in that block. i was trying with regex capture which seemed quite complex.. this answer seemed to be the easiest way..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match that family of characters in the string this regex would put it in the first matching group.

```
/[a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z]+-[a-z]+-([0-9a-z]+).*
```

If you're trying to match that exact string, there's no need for a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want that specific string, there is no need for a regex. If you simply want to know if the large string contains the string you are looking for, try

`inputString.Contains("785452145x");`

Which will give you a bool indicating whether or not the string was found.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a regex...

```
string answer = Regex.Match(input, @"^/.+-(.+)/.+").Groups[1].Value;
```